# Cannot save data in Phpmyadmin using Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to make an event app containing a registration page at Android Studio 3.5. The backend server is using Phpmyadmin using local host.  The connection between local host and the Phpmyadmin is successful.  But, when I try to register a new account using emulator, no data can be saved in the backend.  Any problem in the code?

Php file

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","usbw","social");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]);

    $con->set_charset("UTF8");

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO register(name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $reponse = array();
    $response["success"] = true;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Andriod studio

```
package com.example.home;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name, email, password;
    Button submit;
    String result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(multiThread);
                thread.start();

                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/Connect.php");
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.connect();

                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                    if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"), 8);
                        String box = "";
                        String line = null;

                        while((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
                            box += line + "\n";
                        }

                        inputStream.close();
                        result = box;
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    result = e.toString();
                }

                if (name.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    name.setError("請輸入名字");
                    name.requestFocus();
                } else if (email.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    email.setError("請輸入有效電郵地址");
                    email.requestFocus();
                } else if (password.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()){
                    password.setError("請輸入密碼");
                    password.requestFocus();
                } else if (name.length() < 6) {
                    name.setError("用戶名長度必須最少為6");
                    name.requestFocus();
                } else if (password.length() < 8){
                    password.setError("密碼長度必須最少為8");
                    password.requestFocus();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainLastPage.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isPassword(String password){
        final String Password_PATTERN = "^(?![0-9])(?![0-9]+$)(?![a-zA-Z]+$)[0-9A-Za-z]{6,16}$";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Password_PATTERN);
        pattern.matcher(password).matches();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean name(){
        String user = name.getText().toString().trim();
        if (user.isEmpty()) {
            name.setError("請輸入名字!");
            return false;
        } else if (!isPassword(user)) {
            password.setError("請輸入密碼!");
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private Runnable multiThread = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    submit.setText(result);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHPmyadmin? Isn't that used just to set up the MySQL database?

Comment: Yes, it's for setting the database.  But I'm not sure which part is erroneous.

Comment: Again, how is that even remotely relevant?

Comment: I'm just a beginner.  Not sure which part of my file is relevant to my problem.  What file should I post here?

Comment: You are confusing the interface you use to access the MySQL database with the database itself.  It connects to the MySQL server, not the phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake is in the PHP file. First of all, you are passing 4 parameters to 3 rows.

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"INSERT INTO register(name, email, password) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $email, $password);
```

In your case, I think you should eliminate one of the '?'.

```
VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Also, you forgot to close the statement, so, at the end:

```
$statement->close();
```

Last but not least, if you are trying to send huge amounts of data you should consider using mysqli_stmt_send_long_data() to send it in packages.